# should I make a git push after finish the feature using git flow?

Tags: git, git-flow

I am using bitbucket and managing with gitflow (or trying to).

My issue is this: I create my feature and i did a

```
git-flow feature finish name
```

So, in a tutorial I read I had to do this

```
git push origin :feature/name
```

Before that, at the bitbucket I could see the branch, after do the git push origin it was deleted, why?

After finish the feature , should I run that push origin command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Before that, at the bitbucket I could see the branch, after do the git push origin it was deleted, why?

The command `git-flow feature finish name` deletes the branch on your computer, and bitbucket deletes the branch after you push the new update(deleting the branch) to bitbucket.

> After finish the feature , should I run that push origin command?

Basically, yes, you should do it. However, if you want to keep the branch on bitbucket as backup, you can skip this step and delete it when you are sure you don't need it anymore.

---

***update for new questions in the comment:***

> where does that code goes? is it merged with the HEAD revision?

Yes, when you "finish" a feature, the branch is merged to `develop`, and the `feature/` branch will be deleted after merging. You can get the code at HEAD of develop afterwards.

> when you use git-flow, the develop and the other branches are created locally only?

YES. Unless you push them to the server (bitbucket, github, or something else)

> if I make a git-flow feature finish it was not deleted from bitbucket, what you mean that it is deleted after I make a new update? you mean if I create another feature?

I meant when you do `git push origin :feature/name`, you push the update(merge the feature branch to develop branch) to bitbucket. And since the update deletes the branch after merging it to develop, bitbucket deletes the branch on the server after getting the update.

> lets say the first developer who uses git-flow commits the branches to the remote server and does not delete it, the release 0.1 will be there and the 0.2 and so on, right? any idea how to do that?

Yes. You only need to do the git-flow logic locally and don't push the update that deletes the branch to the server.

> and , let say the first developer using gitflow commits the develop branch to the head master, is there any way to make all new developers fork from that branch?

Just ask other developers pull every branch from bitbucket and fork from the branch you want. `git-flow` is just a philosophy of using git. All the `feature/`, `release/` things are normal branches with pattern name. Treat them like normal git branches, don't think too much.

Comment: Hi, where does that code goes? is it merged with the HEAD revision? when you use git-flow, the develop and the other branches are created locally only? if I make a git-flow feature finish it was not deleted from bitbucket, what you mean that it is deleted after I make a new update? you mean if I create another feature?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please let me know if you get new questions :)

Comment: Thanks @Brian , excuse me, lets say the first developer who uses git-flow commits the branches to the remote server and does not delete it, the release 0.1 will be there and the 0.2 and so on, right? any idea how to do that? and , let say the first developer using gitflow commits the develop branch to the head master, is there any way to make all new developers fork from that branch? (as it should be according git-flow, shouldnt it?)